# iOS SDK Facebook Login - iOS will ask "Open this page in APPNAME ?" but app is not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I am using iOS SDK Facebook to login into my app.
I have a Facebook login button (my own button, not the one provided) and it shows perfectly either the Facebook App (if is installed) or the Safari, and after that the facebook login page.

After the user do login into Facebook the authorization it shown and everything works fine. In Safari It shows the dialog "Open this page in APPNAME ?" and the app is opened but is not working, I cannot do anything and I need to close it and re-open it so I can use it. Same if the Facebook APP is installed, it shows the app and when going back to my app is now working and showing on the top **Back to Facebook**
Also in the top of my app is showing **Back to Safari**, how do I avoid to this be shown and return to my app?

***EDIT - UPDATE***

I've seen that in de Facebook SDK Guide it explains that with custom buttons you need the following code:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
  [login
    logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
          fromViewController:self
                     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) { 
      NSLog(@"Process error");
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
      NSLog(@"Cancelled");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"Logged in");
    }
  }];
```

I do not have the `fromViewController:self`  and if I added Xcode gives me an error of no visible interface. Do I have and old version of Facebook SDK? How do I see this?

***EDIT 2 - UPDATE***

Checked was the version but this is not the issue, the app still freeze when login through facebook. Now Facebook APP is not showed despite is installed. Facebook SDK version are now:

```
FBSDKCoreKit 4.12.0 (was 4.1.0)
FBSDKLoginKit 4.12.0 (was 4.1.0)
FBSDKShareKit 4.12.0 (was 4.1.0)
```

Checked also the .plist file I do have LSApplicationQueriesSchemes

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>    
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

Also I do have:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>XXXXXX</string>
```

And inside the `CFBundleURLTypes` key:

```
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fbXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
                <string>XXXXXXXXX</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

***EDIT 3 - UPDATE***

So, I manage to do correctly the login through facebook. And enter the APP the problem is not longer with Facebook is within my app an the AppDelegate.m

Comment: how to stop popup "Open this page in APPNAME ?" show up ? i want open my app straight away after user press OK or Cancel. Did you achieve this?

Comment: You can't do it with the newest versions of the iOS, this is an internal matter for Apple that they want to do it like this